# Clicking a menu item that contains submenu items makes the submenu items to hide in QML

Tags: c++, qt, menu, qml, menuitem

So my problem is pretty much that when I click on the menu, and then quickly click on the `menuItem2` (that contains submenu items), the submenu items will appear for 0.5 seconds and then hide. I have to click again or hover again on the `menuItem2` to make the submenu items appear correctly.

The only way to clearly make the submenu items appear is by hovering over `menuItem2` without clicking at all.

This is a problem if I want to release my program on a touch screen, since clicking will make the submenu items to hide (the concept of hovering doesn't really work...).

```
Menu {
      id: menu
      MenuItem {
         text: "menuItem1"
      }
      Menu{
         title: "menuItem2"
         MenuItem {
            id: subMenuItem1
            objectName: "subMenuItem1"
            text: "subMenuItem1"
         }
         MenuItem {
            id: subMenuItem2
            objectName: "subMenuItem2"
            text: "subMenuItem2"
         }
      }   
}
```

Thank you for any solution to this problem.